# How can I modify vertical space between multiple sub-figures

Tags: spacing

I'd like to reduce the vertical space between graphics included in my figure.
It looks like that:

```
\begin{figure}[H] 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3.in,width=6in]{pics3/LCCohResEW.pdf}   
    \includegraphics[height=3.in,width=6in]{pics3/CBDCohResEW.pdf}      
    \includegraphics[height=2.05in,width=2.98in]{pics3/LCYearResEW.pdf} 
    \includegraphics[height=2.05in,width=2.98in]{pics3/CBDYearResEW.pdf}    
    \includegraphics[height=2.05in,width=2.98in]{pics3/LCAgeResEW.pdf}
    \includegraphics[height=2.05in,width=2.98in]{pics3/CBDAgeResEW.pdf}                             
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{figure}
```

The plan is to have 4 panels with graphics and i want to reduce the vertical space between them.

I tried adding `\vspace{-something}` but it does not seem to work as placed.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The easy way is to use tabular instead of subfigure.

Comment: Ignore previous comment.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Your MWE creates a column of figures that greatly exceed the page, with almost no space between the images.

Comment: I see. I was trying to limit the vertical gap between the subfigures, which as you showed does not exist. My problem were the margins of the subgraphs themselves.

Comment: You could also overlap the images using \raisebox

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue caused by whitespace in the images to be included, not space added by (La)TeX.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, just an actual MWE.

```
\documentclass[legalpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3.in,width=6in]{example-image-a}\\
    \includegraphics[height=3.in,width=6in]{example-image-b}\\
    \includegraphics[height=2.05in,width=2.98in]{example-image-c} %
    \includegraphics[height=2.05in,width=2.98in]{example-image-a}\\
    \includegraphics[height=2.05in,width=2.98in]{example-image-b} %
    \includegraphics[height=2.05in,width=2.98in]{example-image-c}         
    \caption{caption}
    \label{label}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image: too big]